# How to import all the files in a directory in Python3?

Tags: python, import, directory

I'm writing a small package which has several .py files in it, and probably more files will be added to this package in future. Each file contains a class with the same name as the file. Here's an example:

```
pkg/
pkg/__init__.py
pkg/A.py # in which a class "A" exists
pkg/B.py # in which a class "B" exists
    ...
```

And I imported all the files in __init__.py like this:

```
from .A import A
from .B import B
...
```

But as I mentioned, the number of files are growing, and I don't want to edit __init__.py each time when I add new files into the package. Is there a way to import all the files into __init__.py?

Note: There won't be any sub-directories in pkg.

Update: It'll be great if user can use

```
import pkg.A
import pkg.B
...
```

to import my classes.

Comment: `import pkg` ? ...

Answer (score 0):

first create a `__init__.py` in the pkg folder
and type

```
import os, pkgutil
__all__ = list(module for _, module, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([os.path.dirname(__file__)])
```

or

simply type

```
import A
import B
```

in the `__init__.py` file

and then
use

```
from pkg import *
```

or

```
import pkg
```

`pkg.A` etc will work then

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I noticed that when using your solution, user should write "pkg.A.A" to access the class. I wonder if there is a way that user only needs to write "pkg.A"?